# How do I include the filename in an uglify banner in grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt to minify some JS files. It would be nice to include the filename in the banner. I have found several examples how to include the package name in the banner, but I haven't yet managed to get the filename in there. So: What do I have to put in the gruntfile (see below) instead of pkg.name to get the source filename (or the dest filename) in there?

Thanks in advance

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   // Project configuration.
   grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      uglify: {
         options: {
            banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
         },
         build: {
            files: [{
               expand: true,
               src: '**/*.js',
               dest: 'build',
               cwd: 'src',
               ext: '.min.js'
            }]
         }
      }
   });

   // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

   // Default task(s).
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing, and couldn't find any reference to the current filename that was exposed to the template. Here's the workaround I finally figured out; it's a custom task that dynamically creates a new target for each file:

```js
grunt.registerMultiTask('minify', function () {
    this.files.forEach(function (file) {
        var path = file.src[0],
            target = path.match(/src\/(.*)\.js/)[1];

        // store some information about this file in config
        grunt.config('ugtargets.' + target, {
            path: path,
            filename: path.split('/').pop()
        });

        // create and run an uglify target for this file
        grunt.config('uglify.' + target + '.files', [{
            src: [path],
            dest: path.replace(/^src\/(.*)\.js$/, 'build/$1.min.js')
        }]);
        grunt.task.run('uglify:' + target);
    });
});
```

And my uglify config:

```js
uglify: {
    options: {
        banner: 'Filename: <% ugtargets[grunt.task.current.target].filename %>\n'
    }
}
```

- For each file in your source directory, we create a target name out of the filename. The exact process will depend on how your files are named; you'll want to strip out any dots or slashes. Here I used a regex; in my app I actually used `fs` to read some JSDoc data from the files themselves.
- Then we store that filename in an object in the Grunt configuration, indexed by the target name. Here I used an object with a couple of properties; you could add more stuff here or just use a plain string if you wanted.
- Finally we add a target configuration to the uglify config. This is just the `src` and `dest` for the current file; we have to do our own filename processing but it's not much work. Then we run the uglify task with the new target.

In the banner template, you can now use `grunt.task.current.target` to grab the data we stored in the config earlier. Presto!

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more scripts to be uglify is convenient to separate it to particular subtasks with custom property as name identifier.

```
    uglify: {
        options: {
            banner: 
            '<% var subtask = uglify[grunt.task.current.target]; %>' +
            '/* <%= subtask.name %> <%= pkg.version %> (<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd, HH:MM") %>)\n' +
            ' */\n'
        },
        main: {
            name: 'main.min.js',
            files: [{
                src: 'build/files/js/main.min.js',
                dest: 'build/files/js/main.min.js'
            }]
        },
        vendor: {
            name: 'vendor.min.js',
            files: [{
                src: 'build/files/js/vendor.min.js',
                dest: 'build/files/js/vendor.min.js'
            }]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
banner: grunt.file.read('./folder/file.js'),
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854998/dynamic-mapping-and-concat-with-grunt-uglify/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854998/dynamic-mapping-and-concat-with-grunt-uglify/38858781#38858781)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mattstyles/grunt-banner/issues/5#issuecomment-33445038

process: function (src, filepath) {} did the job.

For me, I wanna add "//# sourceUrl=xxx.min.js" at the bottom of each uglified .min.js so that I can debug these dynamically loaded .min.js. The following simple Gruntfile.js works for me:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    var cwd = "/Branding/Layouts/JS/";
    var src = [
                "file1.js",
                "file2.js",
                "file3.js"
    ];

    var minified_src = [];
    for (i=0;  i< src.length; i++)
        minified_src.push(src[i].replace(/\.js$/g, ".min.js"));

    var config = grunt.initConfig({
        "uglify": {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            },
            target: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: cwd,
                        src: src,
                        dest: cwd,
                        ext: ".min.js",
                        extDot: "last"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        concat: {
            options: {
                process: function (src, filepath) {
                    return src + "\n//# sourceURL=" + filepath.split("/").slice(-1);
                }
            },
            target: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: cwd,
                        src: minified_src,
                        dest: cwd
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'concat']);
};
```

Note: uglify can't preserve a comment that is not inside a code block (like //# sourceMap=xxx.js), I have to use concat to append the comment after uglify is done.

Wow, this is my first stackoverflow post.

Answer (score -1):

Documentation is indeed scarse, but `<%= pkg.name %>` in the banner string implies you can also do `<% for ( var s in grunt) { %> \ngrunt.<%=s%><% } %>` or even `<% for ( var s in this) { %> \nthis.<%=s%><% } %>`.

So (after some searching) to get the filename you can do this:

`var bannerTemplate = '<%'
    +'  var subtask = uglify[grunt.task.current.target];'
    +'  var file = subtask?subtask.dest:\'\';'
    +'  var filename = file.split(\'/\').pop();'
    +'%>'
    +'/*! <%= filename %>'
    +'\n * version: <%= pkg.version %>'
    +'\n * author: <%= pkg.author %>'
    +'\n */\n';`