# Dynamic Mapping and Concat with Grunt Uglify

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm trying to use [dynamic mapping](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) AND concat Javascript files with Grunt Uglify.

I have the following which is not working correctly.

Here is my folder structure:

```
javascript
    |- account
        |- custom.js
    |- bills
        |- billing-one.js
        |- billing-two.js
    |- test (output folder)
```

Here is what I'm expecting:

```
javascript
    |- account
        |- custom.js
    |- bills
        |- billing-one.js
        |- billing-two.js
    |- test
        |- billing-one.min.js (this file includes billing-one.js AND custom.js)
        |- billing-two.min.js (this file includes billing-two.js AND custom.js)
```

This is what I'm currently getting:

```
javascript
    |- account
        |- custom.js
    |- bills
        |- billing-one.js
        |- billing-two.js
    |- test
        |- bills
            |- billing-one.min.js (this file includes just billing-one.js)
            |- billing-two.min.js (this file includes just billing-two.js)
        |- account 
            |- custom.min.js (this file includes just custom.js)
```

It is not including the custom.js file but instead creates a 2 folders `test/account/custom.min.js`
'test/bills/billing-one.js' - see above

```
options: {
    beautify: true,
    mangle: false,
    compress: false,
    preserveComments: 'all'
},
files: [
  {
    expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
    cwd: 'javascript/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
    src: [[bills/*.js'], 'account/custom.js'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
    dest: 'test/',   // Destination path prefix.
    ext: '.min.js',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
    extDot: 'first'   // Extensions in filenames begin after the first dot
  },
],
```

I want all the Javascript files within the `bills/` folder to contain custom.js

So if there are 2 files:
`bills/billing-one.js`
`bills/billing-two.js`

I would expect test/ folder to include

`test/billing-one.min.js` (this file would contain billing-one + custom.js)
`test/billing-two.min.js` (this file would contain billing-two + custom.js)

I don't want to hard code the file names in. If more files are added to`bills/` folder the should be concat and output to the `test/` folder.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE SINCE ANSWER ACCEPTED:**

Use the follow updated code to make sure this works as intended - otherwise you'll run into errors when running GRUNT.

I did try adding this to the answer by submitting an edit for review. But it got rejected, twice, by the all knowing all superior mods... when in fact it's a valid input and improves on the answer given. Note the `[]`, `cwd` and `src` changes.

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'javascript/bills/',
    src: ['*.js'],
    dest: 'test/',
    ext: '.min.js',
    extDot: 'first'
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the banner property of grunt-contrib-uglify to append the content.
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#banner

Here is the grunt configuration:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: grunt.file.read('./javascript/account/custom.js'),
        beautify: true,
        mangle: false,
        compress: false,
        preserveComments: 'all'
      },
      files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'javascript/',
        src: ['bills/*.js'],
        dest: 'test/',
        ext: '.min.js',
        extDot: 'first'
      },
    }
  });
```

In the above configuration every file in the bills folder will get the content of custom.js configured in the banner property.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks - works nicely. I've searched the docs and trying to figure out a way to include multiple files in the banner for example:  `banner: grunt.file.read([ ./javascript/account/custom.js', ./javascript/account-2/custom.js ]),` But that doesn't work.

Comment: Found a work around for the above comment by using concat on multiple files and then including the concated file in the banner