# Error: ENOENT in Grunt uglify task

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I have the following gruntfile.js. Using [grunt-contrib-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-concat) and [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify) together.

This is an extention of a developement asked @[Dynamic Mapping and Concat with Grunt Uglify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854998/dynamic-mapping-and-concat-with-grunt-uglify/38858781#38858781)

I use `banner` in the `uglify` task to reference a file created in the `concat` task.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    // Configure task(s)
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        // setup concats
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';\n',
            },
            dev: {
                files: [{
                    src: [
                        'sports.js',
                        'salon.js',
                        'offRoad.js',
                    ],
                    dest: 'src/js/concat/car-dev.js'
                }],
            },
        },

        // setup uglify task
        // this will produce a car js file (which includes car-dev.js) for every car js file located within scr/js/cars/
        uglify: {
            // dev - use in development mode, global overrides section
            dev: {
                options: {
                    // include concat dev.js
                    banner: grunt.file.read('src/js/concat/car-dev.js'),
                    beautify: true,
                    mangle: false,
                    compress: false,
                    preserveComments: 'all'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/js/cars/',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: 'javascript/dev',
                    ext: '.dev.js',
                    extDot: 'first'
                }],
            },
        },
    });

    // Load the plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

    // Register task(s)
    grunt.registerTask('default',
        'concat:dev'
        'uglify:dev'
    ]);
};
```

My issue is that if `src/js/concat/car-dev.js` doesn't exist, I get the following error:

`Error: Unable to read "src/js/concat/car-dev.js" file <Error code: ENOENT).`

If I create an empty file `@src/js/concat/car-dev.js` the `grunt` command works fine.

However this is not always possible. I want uglify to reference the `car-dev.js` file even if it doesn't exist.  What I'm looking for is someway to reference the `grunt->concat->dev->files->dest` file.

I've tried adding the following

```
banner: grunt.file.read(grunt.concat.dev.files.dest),
```

and

```
banner: grunt.concat.dev.files.dest
```

but neither work. Is this possible?
This is not a task dependency issue - the error gets thrown before any tasks are run because banner: `src/js/concat/car-dev.js` does not exist.

Any help - much appreciated.